# PostgreSQL - Find ALL Privileges for a Group

Tags: postgresql

I have been attempting to remove a group role from an AWS PostgreSQL instance, and I've gotten stuck.  I have successfully removed all dependencies from the group, except for 6, and I have no idea what those might be.  I will explain what I have attempted to use to find these missing privileges, and I really appreciate some direction as to where I can look next.  Each of these steps were performed on all of the databases and schemas within the Instance:

1. I used the following code to revoke all privileges from the group

   ```
   REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE {dbname} FROM GROUP "Application_Access";
   REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM GROUP "Application_Access";
   REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA  public  FROM GROUP "Application_Access";
   REVOKE ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public  FROM GROUP "Application_Access";
   REVOKE ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public  FROM GROUP "Application_Access";
   ```
2. I used the psql commands to list all objects and their privileges, and this is what I found

   - \z = Nothing listed for Application_Access
   - \du and \dg = Application_Access - No inheritance, Cannot login, Member of {}
   - \d = All relations owned by OurAdmin
   - \db = All tablespaces owned by rdsadmin (AWS Admin)
   - \dtisv = Nothing
   - \ddp = This command is the only one showing Application_Access 
     [Results of \ddp Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGQEf.png)
3. I understand that \ddp shows default privileges for future database additions.  I attempted to run ALTER PRIVILEGES commands.  It forced me to make myself a member of Application_Access (ERROR: Must be a member of Role. why?!?) in order to run the command.  This reassigned all of my privileges back to Application_Access and I was back to square one.

   ```
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON ROLE "Application_Access" REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE {dbname} FROM "Application_Access";
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON ROLE "Application_Access" REVOKE ALL ON ALL SCHEMAS FROM "Application_Access";
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON ROLE "Application_Access" REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM "Application_Access";
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON ROLE "Application_Access" REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM "Application_Access";
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ON ROLE "Application_Access" REVOKE ALL ON SEQUENCES FROM "Application_Access";
   ```

   - I reran all of my previous steps, however, now when I run \ddp on all databases, it has added the first 3 lines that you see in the attached image above.
4. I have a script that I found and altered to show me all of the privileges on each database.  I can pass it a Role to simplify the search.  It isn't showing Application_Access as being associated with any objects either.

   ```
   SELECT  relacl
       , SUBSTRING(
          CASE WHEN strpos('r', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', SELECT'     ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('w', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', UPDATE'     ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('a', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', INSERT'     ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('d', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', DELETE'     ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('R', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', RULE'       ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('x', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', REFERENCES' ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('t', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', TRIGGER'    ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('X', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', EXECUTE'    ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('U', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', USAGE'      ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('C', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', CREATE'     ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN strpos('T', SPLIT_PART( SPLIT_PART( ARRAY_TO_STRING( RELACL, '|' ), pu.groname, 2 ) , '/', 1 ) ) > 0 THEN ', TEMPORARY'  ELSE '' END
          , 3,10000)
       || namespace ||'.'|| item ||' TO '|| pu.groname ||' ;' AS grantsql
   FROM    (SELECT      use.usename AS subject
                   ,nsp.nspname AS namespace
                   ,cls.relname AS item
                   ,cls.relkind AS type
                   ,use2.usename AS owner
                   ,cls.relacl
       FROM        pg_user     use 
       CROSS JOIN  pg_class    cls
       LEFT JOIN   pg_namespace nsp 
       ON          cls.relnamespace = nsp.oid 
       LEFT JOIN   pg_user      use2 
       ON          cls.relowner = use2.usesysid
       WHERE       cls.relowner = use.usesysid
       AND         nsp.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
       ORDER BY     subject
                   ,namespace
                   ,item ) as x
   JOIN    pg_group pu ON array_to_string(relacl, '|') LIKE '%'|| pu.groname ||'%' 
   WHERE   relacl IS NOT NULL
   AND     relacl::text LIKE '%Application%'
   ORDER BY 2
   ```

***Based on everything that you see above, is there anything that anyone can think of that I left out, or didn't do correctly/completely? How can I resolve the default privileges - ALTER PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL didn't work.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took several days, but I guess I finally asked Google the right question.  I thought I would post my solution in case anyone might be having a similar problem on PostgreSQL:

I was close with my ALTER PRIVILEGES commands.  In this screenshot (psql command \ddp)- [image: Default Privileges]

there are 4 columns: Owner, Schema, Type, and Access Privilege.  You will need each of these columns to generate the ALTER PRIVILEGES commands:

- Owner - This is the user/group that will have the privileges altered - seemed weird to me too.  :)
- Schema - This is the schema containing the commands to assign the default privileges
- Type - This will tell you what type of REVOKE command you need to use
- Access Privilege - This is the user/group that you can't drop because "it has dependencies"

Based on this list, your command structure will look similar to this - filling {} in from above:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE {Owner} IN SCHEMA {Schema} REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON {Type} FROM {Access Privilege};
```

In order to perform this command, you must be logged into the Postgres database as either the Owner, or a member of the Owner group, otherwise, you will get the error "ERROR: Must be a member of Role {Owner}."

I had to perform 2 sets of ALTER PRIVILEGES - logging into the database as the owner dbac and Application_Access.

Logging in as Application_Access and executing the commands below eliminated the first 3 rows (where Application_Access is the Owner) from the above screenshot of the \ddp psql command.

```
alter default privileges for role "Application_Access" in schema public revoke all privileges on functions from "Application_Access";
alter default privileges for role "Application_Access" in schema public revoke all privileges on sequences from "Application_Access";
alter default privileges for role "Application_Access" in schema public revoke all privileges on tables from "Application_Access";
```

Logging in as dbac and executing the commands below eliminated the other rows (where dbac is the Owner) from the above screenshot of the psql \ddp command.

```
alter default privileges for role "dbac" in schema public revoke all privileges on functions from "Application_Access";
alter default privileges for role "dbac" in schema public revoke all privileges on sequences from "Application_Access";
alter default privileges for role "dbac" in schema public revoke all privileges on tables from "Application_Access";
```